# option_groups_from_collection_for_select using three tables in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select, form-for, actionview

Generally we show option_groups_from_collection_for_select to group data using two tables such as cities as per provinces. That's pretty simple and I have done it.

Here I have a to show locations(from Locations table) grouped into cities(from City table) and cities grouped into Provinces(from provinces table). I am not able to figure out whether its even possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just refer to [select_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) document here

We can create a select tag like this example

```
= select_tag '', options_for_select([ ["Option 1", 1], ["Option 2", 2] ])
```

For simply, your work is just how to create this array from the query

```
[ ["Option 1", 1], ["Option 2", 2] ]
```

Comment: I need a group within a group. This is not applicable here